# JavaScript call multi function, but input value is output from last function

Tags: javascript, function, methods, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I have a function like that:

```
function intiFun(initValue) {

    const firstResult = firstFun(initValue);
    const secondResult = secondFun(firstResult);
    const thirdResult = thirddFun(secondResult);
    const fourthResult = fourthFun(thirdResult);
    return fourthResult;
}
```

but i want to write it better. and i dont want to save value from each function as variable.

is there any solution to to call functions with out save old value

like rxjs or somthing like that:

```
function intiFun(initValue) {
    return firstFun(initValue).secondFun().thirddFun().fourthFun();
}
```

or more better like that:

```
function intiFun(initValue) {
    return firstFun(initValue)         
          .secondFun(secondInput)
          .thirddFun(secondInput)
          .fourthFun(secondInput)
}

function secondFun(value, secondInput) {
    return ...;
}
...
```

or some liberally to do that (maybe lodash)

Comment: "i dont want to save value from each function as variable" — That's a desire you would benefit from getting over. Writing it that way is (a) very clear and (b) very easy to add logging debug statements to.

Comment: Right to you, its very easy to debug. but out of curiosity, i would like to know is there any way to that?

Comment: If you want chaining, you would need to create a constructor, then add instance functions, and return the instance in those functions

Comment: tnx, i thing, i should stay in old login. Every solution make it complicates

Comment: You should really accept an answer.

Comment: Just write `function initFun(initValue) {
    return fourthFun(thirddFun(secondFun(firstFun(initValue))));
}`?

Comment: I thing, the answer for @MatíasFidemraizer is the best solution, because its curry and we can send more than one input to functions

Comment: but the answer for @AaditMShah is correct too

Comment: I never provided an answer. I just said that you should accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pipe`, manual currying & partial application to the rescue:

```js
const pipe = funs => x =>
  funs.reduce ((o, fun) => fun (o), x)

const f = x => x + 1
const g = x => y => x + y * 2
const h = x => x * x
const i = x => y => z => x + y / z + 3
const j = x => x + 5

const init = pipe ([
   f
  ,g (4)
  ,h
  ,i (10) (33)
  ,j
])

const input = 1
const output = init (input)

console.log (output)
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you're looking for **function composition**: we can construct the composite function from an array of functions in JavaScript using for example `reduce` (with the initial value being the identity function `(v) => v`:

```js
const composeAll = (functions) => functions.reduce(
  (composition, f) => 
    ((v) => f(composition(v))),
  (v) => v
);
 
const firstFun = (s) => `${s}a`;
const secondFun = (s) => `${s}b`;
const thirdFun = (s) => `${s}c`;
const fourthFun = (s) => `${s}d`;
const intiFun = composeAll([firstFun, secondFun, thirdFun, fourthFun]);

console.log(intiFun(''));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
abcd
```

---

**NOTES:**

As you can see, `composeAll` creates a chained function call by wrapping each function `f` in an arrow function which takes a value `v`, executes it on the composite function constructed from the preceding functions in the array and finally passes the result to `f`.

You can convince yourself that the construction is correct by induction over the array length: if we define the composition of an empty list of functions to be the identity function then

- in the **base case** (for a singleton array `[f]` with length 1) the result is

  `(v) => f((v => v)(v)) === (v) => f(v)`
- in the **step case** (for an array with length `n`) assume the function obtained for the `n-1` preceding functions in the array was correctly constructed (let this be `g`), then the result is

  `(v) => f_n(g(v)) === (v) => f_n(f_n-1(...(f_0(v))...))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
const firstFun  = x => x + 1;
const secondFun = x => x + 1;
const thirdFun  = x => x + 1;
const fourthFun = x => x + 1;

const pipe = (...functions) => x => functions.reduce((x, f) => f(x), x);

const initFun = pipe(firstFun, secondFun, thirdFun, fourthFun);

console.log(initFun(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const firstFun  = x => { /* return ... */ };
const secondFun = x => { /* return ... */ };
const thirdFun  = x => { /* return ... */ };
const fourthFun = x => { /* return ... */ };

const callAll= (value, ...functions) => {
   functions.forEach(fn => value = fn(value));
   retrun value;
}

const result = callAll(3, firstFun, secondFun, thirdFun, fourthFun);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function initFun(initValue) {
    return fourthFun(thirddFun(secondFun(firstFun(initValue))));
}
```

Alternatively, convert your function into promises:

```
function initFun(initValue) {
    return firstFun(initValue)
        .then(secondFun)
        .then(thirddFun)
        .then(fourthFun);
}
```

Comment: :)) i know that but after 1 month its very hard to read and understand

Comment: promises it good solution, tnx. but my function have to be synchronize not a-sync. maybe in other case i can use it  ;)

Comment: +1 for the first snippet, -1 for the second. Abusing promises as an identity container is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're looking for can be achieved using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
let log = (head, ...args) => { console.log('log:', head, ...args); return head },
    firstFun  = (str, ...args) => log(str, ...args) + ' firstFun',
    secondFun = (str, ...args) => log(str, ...args) + ' secondFun',
    thirddFun = (str, ...args) => log(str, ...args) + ' thirddFun',
    fourthFun = (str, ...args) => log(str, ...args) + ' fourthFun';

function initFun(initValue) {
  let functions = [
    [firstFun],
    [secondFun, 'extra argument'],
    [thirddFun],
    [fourthFun, "I'm here too"],
  ];

  return functions.reduce((result, [fn, ...args]) => fn(result, ...args), initValue);
}

console.log( 'result: ' + initFun('foo bar') );
```

Keep in mind that I log the incomming arguments of the methods, not the resulting value. This means that for example `secondFun` (`log: foo bar firstFun extra argument`) has the argument `'foo bar firstFun'` and `'extra argument'`. But you only see the added string `'secondFun'` when `thirdFun` is called (since it is given as the argument).

Comment: With partial application, you don't have to pass in extra arguments. You could instead write `const initFun = initValue => [firstFun, secondFun.bind(null, "extra argument"), thirdFun, fourthFun.bind(null, "I'm here too")].reduce((x, f) => f(x), initValue);`. If `secondFun` and `fourthFun` are curried, then you don't even have to use `.bind`.

Answer (score -1):

### Bad Method — See Below

<s>If you want something like `a.firstFunc().secondFunc().thirdFunc().fourthFunc()`, you should define those functions to `Object.prototype` (or `Number.prototype`, `String.prototype`, etc.):</s>

```
Object.prototype.firstFunc = function() {
    var value = this;
    // ...
    return something;
};
Object.prototype.secondFunc = function() {
    var value = this;
    // ...
    return something;
};
Object.prototype.thirdFunc = function() {
    var value = this;
    // ...
    return something;
};
Object.prototype.fourthFunc = function() {
    var value = this;
    // ...
    return something;
};
```

***P.S.*** "Function" is normally shortened to "func" but not "fun".

---

### Update

If you want something like `myObject(a).firstFunc().secondFunc().thirdFunc().fourthFunc()`, you should:

```
var myObject = function(value) {
    this.value = value;
};
myObject.prototype.firstFunc = function() {
    var value = this.value;
    // ...
    return something;
};
myObject.prototype.secondFunc = function() {
    var value = this.value;
    // ...
    return something;
};
myObject.prototype.thirdFunc = function() {
    var value = this.value;
    // ...
    return something;
};
myObject.prototype.fourthFunc = function() {
    var value = this.value;
    // ...
    return something;
};
```

Comment: This is terrible advice. Don't define methods on native prototypes unless you're monkey patching.